# Webdriver-Manager Update in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

Having experienced issues previously with `webdriver-manager update`in Azure Pipelines, I thought to add an additional copy of this command to run if the first one failed.
[image]
That works nicely - although I still wish `webdriver-manager update` would always work first time!

However, if the second command is required, the test shows as a fail even though the actual tests being run, pass.
[image]

If the second command is not required (it is marked as "skipped"), all is well and providing the actual tests pass, I get a correct outcome.

So my query is, is it possible to 'ignore' the failed first update and to show the pipeline as a pass (providing the tests pass of course)!

I've attached snapshots of the two Update command setups:
[image]
And
[image]

Thank you.

For the sake of completeness, here's error for when the update fails:

```
2019-09-19T10:44:50.9881873Z ##[section]Starting: Webdriver-Manager Update
2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064449Z 

2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064522Z Task         : Command Line
2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064560Z Description  : Run a command line with 
arguments
2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064612Z Version      : 1.1.3
2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064666Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064703Z Help         : [More Information] 
(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613735)
2019-09-19T10:44:51.0064738Z 



2019-09-19T10:44:51.0162388Z ##[command]node 
node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
2019-09-19T10:44:51.7954075Z [11:44:51] I/config_source - curl - 
oC:\vsts\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.140.0\_work\64\s\node_modules\webdriver- 
manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium- 
release.storage.googleapis.com/
2019-09-19T10:44:51.8085038Z [11:44:51] I/config_source - curl - 
oC:\vsts\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.140.0\_work\64\s\node_modules\webdriver- 
manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml 
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
2019-09-19T10:44:51.8148392Z [11:44:51] I/config_source - curl - 
oC:\vsts\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.140.0\_work\64\s\node_modules\webdriver- 
manager\selenium\gecko-response.json 
https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4275157Z events.js:183
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4276258Z       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4279198Z       ^
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4280058Z 
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4280232Z Error: read ECONNRESET
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4280279Z     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4632661Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2019-09-19T10:44:52.4649070Z ##[section]Finishing: Webdriver-Manager 
Update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a failed task in your build pipeline, the build pipeline will display the failed status. It worked as designed. And if you check the Continue on error condition, when your first task failed, the build pipeline will display partially succeeded.
[image]

If you want this status, then your running logic should be changed. You should set a pipeline variables first, like this
[image]

In your first task you should update the variable value to false after the update command. And set the second task running condition like this.
[image]

It means, if your first task failed, the variable value will not change, and the value matched the second task’s custom condition, so the second task will run. If your first task succeed, the variable value will change and then the second task will not run.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Wang-MSFT